# Nginx doesn't recognise mp4_limit_rate directive

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Nginx 1.4.6(Ubuntu) and installed nginx-extras (apt-get install nginx-extras). I config my site with:

```
location ~ *.mp4$ {
     mp4;
     mp4_buffer_size       1m;
     mp4_max_buffer_size   5m;
     mp4_limit_rate        on;
     mp4_limit_rate_after  30s
    }
```

But Nginx alert me: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "mp4_limit_rate" in  .....

What's wrong in my configuration?

Please show me how to resolve this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: It's nginx+ feature. You have to pay for it.«This directive is available as part of our commercial subscription» http://nginx.org/r/mp4_limit_rate

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the question itself so it should be left open. The fact that the problem stems from the user not having a paid subscription doesn't justify closing it, I don't think.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:
Replace mp4_limit_rate and limit_rate_after with:

limit_rate            260k;   # about 2mbit

limit_rate_after      3m;

If you have video files with different bitrates you can specify more locations in your nginx.conf with different limits.

Answer (score 0):

check nginx modules correct install and exists.
because your config get directive error and not founded mp4 modules

RESOLED : [see here](https://serverfault.com/questions/342358/nginx-add-enable-mp4-module)

```
ls /usr/share/nginx/modules-*
# OR
ls /etc/nginx/moduels-enable
```